# Is there any solution for this

Tags: magento, paypal, admin, magento-1.9

I want to configure paypal in my magento website. I have this problem with my magento admin panel: When I go under System-Configuration-Sales and check Payment Methods I get the error below. Can anyone help me fix this?

Thank you

[image: Error message]

Comment: Error 500 menas something is wrong in your code. Try to disable added modules, clean cache and sessions (delete all in) root/var/cache/ and root/var/sessions. Eventually disable compilation.

Comment: You can view error message by enabling (uncommenting) line with ini-set display errors in root/index.php

Comment: go to index.php file present in root of the site and than uncomment below line and check what error is coming :

#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);